# prevent coder error - forget to add "::type" in "std::enable_if<>::type" (SFINAE)

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

Here is a correct code of SFINAE (**[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6939426dc6b03703)**) :-

```
template<bool b> class C {
    public: template<bool b2=b> typename std::enable_if<b2,void>::type f(){
        cout<<"no!!";
    }
};
int main() {
    //C<false> c1; c1.f(); <-- not compilable (it is good)
    C<true> c2; c2.f();
    return 0;
}
```

I am very new to C++ and still not accustom to it.
As a result, I often forget to add `::type` :-

```
    public: template<bool b2=b> std::enable_if<b2,void> f(){
        cout<<"no!!";
    }
```

Unfortunately, even it is wrong, it is compilable for `<false>` (**[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/927695a4a782e67c)**).

In my bad day, I even go far as :-

```
    public: std::enable_if<b,void> f(){
        cout<<"no!!";
    }
```

It is still compilable for `<false>`! (**[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68201777974deedd)**).

I know how/why it is wrong, but I often make such mistake in practice.

**Question:**
Besides compiler warning, how to prevent coder's error in this situation?

Comment: why compiler warnings aside? They are made to prevent such errors. If you like use the `-Werror` flag to make sure it wont compile succesful

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled.  That should give you a warning about not returning a value from a non-void function.  [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b331b8b07a29d516)

Comment: @tobi303  It may sound so amateur, but I love to know if there are other fool-proofs.  More = Better. XD

Comment: warnings are fool-proof if you treat them as errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++14 introduced `std::enable_if_t` which doesn't allow this mistake to be made, by no longer requiring the programmer to refer to a nested type explicitly. You can decide for your own code that `enable_if` should simply no longer be used at all, perhaps even blacklisting it in your own source code.

Comment: Do you happen to also know about foolproof for the second case `public: std::enable_if<b,void> f()`?

Comment: @javaLover If you do blacklist `enable_if`, that already doesn't work.

Comment: @javaLover it's wrong code anyway (your second case), even with the `::type` written and even with `enable_if_t`.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb  Yes, I just realized it.  Thank.